# jQuery document ready call sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following problem with jQuery. I use this code:

```
function populate_select_from_json(select, json_url) {
    select.empty();
    $.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", value.name)
                .text(value.title)
                .appendTo(select);
        });
    });
    select.children(":first").attr("selected", true);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value_type = $("#value_type");
    populate_select_from_json(value_type, SOME_URL);

    var unit = $("#unit");
    populate_select_from_json(unit, ANOTHER_URL + value_type.val());

});
```

I wanted to:

1. Load the document
2. Get some JSON data from an associated database
3. Put the data in `#value_type <select>` item
4. Get the value of `#value_type` select, and query the database once again to populate another select item.

The problem is, when I call `value_type.val()`, it always outputs `null`, even though the  `#value_type <select>` is correctly populated. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: **A** jax is **asynchronous**. At the moment you call `value_type.val()`, the field was not populated yet. I recommend to use deferred objects to chain Ajax calls: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/.

Comment: Just what I thought! It looked like the field was not yet populated. Does the browser call my method in another thread so it kind of forks from the .ready callback?

Comment: I guess for retrieving the data, some background process is started, but there are no threads in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose something like this may work better with [`promises`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Along these lines (untested):

```
var populate_select_from_json = function($select, json_url) {
    $select.empty();
    return $.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", value.name)
                .text(value.title)
                .appendTo($select);
        });
        $select.children(":first").attr("selected", true);
    });
};
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $value_type = $("#value_type");
    var $unit = $("#unit");

    populate_select_from_json($value_type, SOME_URL).done(function(){
      populate_select_from_json($unit, ANOTHER_URL + $value_type.val());
    });
});
```